An upper bound for the volume of a polytope inscribed in a ball with a given number of facets
It is known that for every polytope $P=conv(V) \subset B$ inside the unit ball, we have the following inequality for the volume:
$ \left(\frac{Vol(P)}{Vol(B)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \lesssim \sqrt{\frac{1+log \frac{|V|}{n}}{n}}$
for $n < |V| < e^{n}$, and this is asymptotically optimal (see for example: E. D. Gluskin, ''Extremal properties of orthogonal parallelepipeds and their applications to the geometry of Banach spaces''). We call the left hand side the volume-radius of $K$ (as this is the radius of a ball with the same volume as $K$).
I am interested in a corresponding bound for the volume of a polytope with a given number of facets ($(n-1)$-dimensional faces). Observe that for as few as $2n$ facets, we have the normalized cube $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]^{n} \subset B$ and volume-radius is asymptotically $ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}(1 + o(1)) $, in sharp contrast to the vertices situation, where the volume-radius must tend to $0$ whenever $|V|$ is sub-exponential.
It is not clear at all (to me) what should be expected from such a bound. What happens for $n^{2}$ facets, or for some other polynomial? must the volume-radius be bounded away from $1$ in those cases? And generally, what happens when the number of facets is sub-exponential?
